# MySQL update table from other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sql-update

I have two tables: contacts and companies.

```
contacts has : id, group_id, company_id, email, company
companies has: id, group_id, name
```

At the moment, contacts.group_id value is 0 (recently added the column) so does contacts.company value is "".

How should I move the data on

```
companies.group_id to contacts.group_id and companies.name to contacts.company 
based on contacts.company_id = companies.id?
```

I tried the following query but gives me error

```
UPDATE contacts SET contacts.group_id=companies.group_id 
FROM companies WHERE contacts.company_id=companies.id;
```

It gives me this error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 'FROM companies WHERE 
contacts.company_id=companies.id' at line 1
```

I use phpmyadmin to run this query

Comment: It's a syntax error, meaning you can't use the FROM like that in an UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysql lets you do JOINS in your UPDATE statements:

```sql
UPDATE contacts c
INNER JOIN companies co ON c.company_id = co.id 
SET c.group_id = co.group_id,
    c.company = companies.name
```

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html):

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
    SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

> You can also perform UPDATE operations covering multiple tables.
>   However, you cannot use ORDER BY or LIMIT with a multiple-table
>   UPDATE. The table_references clause lists the tables involved in the join.

Comment: is there any different your query with the one from Lajos Query? Both are working.. your query use inner join, while his query does not use join. is there any advantage or disadvantage between this 2 queries?

Comment: Both queries work. Mine is using explicit JOINs, his is using implicit joins with the validation on the WHERE clause. Explicit JOINs are more used these days since they are easier to read and less error prone since you have the validation on the ON clause right in front of the table name.

Comment: How should I proceed if what I want is INSERT instead of UPDATE?

Comment: @Harts. To insert data from one table in another you can use insert into table1(col1,col2) SELECT col1,col2 FROM table2... But i'm not sure if that's what you meant

Comment: Sorry, I did not make it clear, under the same condition from my main question, how should I proceed if I want to do INSERT instead of UPDATE. So, I have two table contact, and companies, I want to move all company data to contacts, so company.name insert into contact.company as a new data. Let me know if it's not clear I will create a new question instead. Thank you

Comment: Yes. It's probably better to create a new question. Put all the relevant information and table structures in there.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could work for you:

```
update
  contacts,
  companies
set
  contacts.group_id=companies.group_id, 
  contacts.company=companies.name
where
  contacts.company_id = companies.id
```